In Canasta, is it possible to pickup a black 3 if it allows to go out?
Can I pickup 3♣ / 3♠ from the discard pile if it has just that card and my hand has two black 3s?

No, you can never pick up the discard pile if the top card is a black 3 (or a wild).
https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta

The discard pile may never be taken when its top card is a wild card, a black three, or a red three.

The only exception in the rules that relates to black threes is that normally you cannot meld black threes, but you can meld them when you are going out. But this is only an exception to the "no melding black threes" rule, it does not relate to the rule about taking the pile with a black three on top.

A set of three or four black threes (without wild cards) may be melded only when a player goes out.


many thanks - in a similar vein I wondered what rules take precedence : a) 2 on top of discard pile can I make a meld with two 2s in my hand and take the discard pile - Presume the anwwer is No. b) Can I make a meld of 3 jokers or three 2s - presume answer is NO.

The pertinent rule being a meld must contain two natural cards and 2s and Jokers are not natural cards?
